# Jsoup Click Links To Get More Data

Tags: jsoup

```
package vinovisionparis;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class vinovisionparis {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          int z = 0;
          for(int page = 0; page<= 1; page++){

              Document doc = null;
              try {
                  doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.vinovisionparis.com/Catalogue-2018/Liste-des-exposants/(search_on)/all/(limit)/48/(sort)/raisonSociale_asc/(page)/" + page).get();
              } catch (IOException iOException) {
              }

Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("div.block.block-page.catal-ex.mod-catal");
for (Element headline : newsHeadlines) {
      z++;
              if(z == 10 ) {break;}
    String title = headline.select("div.catal-ex-item-group-title h3  a").text();
    String desc = headline.select("div.catal-ex-item-desc p.catal-ex-item-country").text();
    String text = headline.select("div.catal-ex-item-desc div.catal-ex-item-txt p").text();
     String loc = headline.select("li").last().text();

    System.out.println(z +" "+ title +"  " + desc + " " + text +" " + loc); 
}


    }
}
}
```

How can i click on the title link to get the remaining data like company website and other details that can be seeing when you click a link ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a link url of href with Element#attr("href).

https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html

If you want to get an absolute path, you have to use Element#attr("abs:href).  You can get a detail page like this.

```
public void test1() {
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.vinovisionparis.com/Catalogue-2018/Liste-des-exposants/(search_on)/all/(limit)/48/(sort)/raisonSociale_asc/(page)/1").get();
        Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("div.catal-ex-item");
        int i = 0;
        for (Element headline : newsHeadlines) {
            i++;
            if(i == 10 ) {break;}
            String title = headline.select("div.catal-ex-item-group-title h3  a").text();

            // get a link to detail page
            Elements aTag = headline.select("div.catal-ex-item-group-title h3  a");
            String detailPageUrl = "";

            // go to a detail page
            String companyPageUrl = "";
            if (!aTag.isEmpty()) {
                detailPageUrl = aTag.attr("abs:href");
                Document doc2 = Jsoup.connect(detailPageUrl).get();
                Elements companyPageLink = doc2.select("a.catal-ed-main-url-link.catal-ed-url-link");
                companyPageUrl = companyPageLink.attr("abs:href");
            }

            String desc = headline.select("div.catal-ex-item-desc p.catal-ex-item-country").text();
            String text = headline.select("div.catal-ex-item-desc div.catal-ex-item-txt p").text();
            System.out.println("----------");
            System.out.println("Title: " + title);
            System.out.println("Desc:"  + desc);
            System.out.println("Text: "+ text);
            System.out.println("CompanyPage: "+ companyPageUrl);
            System.out.println("----------");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```